# Is multifurcation possible?

Tags: chaos-theory, bifurcation

I have recently read on bifurcation in chaos theory. Now, I have a simple question (which hopefully has a simple answer): is this possible to have a family of functions that can model multifurcation (rather than bifurcation)? If yes, is there a general rule to determine what pattern would a type of function produce? for example, if I have $f(x) = rx(1-x)$ can I provisionally say that it would make a bifurcation pattern rather than, let's say, trifurcation? (if it is possible to have a trifurcation).

Comment: There is no such term as "multifurcation", "bifurcation" covers splitting into any number of fixed points, not just two (and also other topology changing behaviors). Splitting into three is called [Pitchfork bifurcation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitchfork_bifurcation). There are "rules" for the number in terms of partial derivatives.

Comment: I thought that a $r$ increased, the $rx(1-x)$ function has a chaotic region, then settles down to non-chaotic behavior again, and then splits in three.

Comment: @Conifold https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/multifurcations#English  it's probably not used much in math though.

Comment: @ conifold, thank you for your comment. So bifurcation is not just limited to 2. Thanks.

Comment: https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Visualizing-Escape-Paths-in-the-Mandelbrot-Set-Burns/a927619b6e0d946b024f07816a56104013642e41

Comment: https://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/~adamcunn/downloads/MandelbrotSet.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your comments.

Comment: https://fractalforums.org/fractal-mathematics-and-new-theories/28/tri-furcation-and-more/1247/msg6431#msg6431

Comment: Thank you Adam for your help.

Answer (score 3):

> Is multifurcation possible?

Yes.  An example is the "[Mandelbrot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set) iteration" $z_{n+1}=z_n+c$ with $z_0=0$: When you transition $c$ from the main [cardioid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardioid) of $M$ to the "arm" bulb labeled "3" in this 
image (or to its complex conjugate mirror), the period will triple, i.e. transition 1→3. [Image source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Mandelbrot_Set_%E2%80%93_Periodicities_coloured.png)
[image]

Or you could transition $c$ from the "head" (the circle around −1 with label "2") to one of the attached "ears" with label "6" and you get two "trifurcations" 2→6.

When you transition from the main body cardioid to a bulb with label "5", you'll get period 1→5.

For the main cardioid, the two "arms" of order 3 are sprouting at
$$c=c(\mu)=\frac\mu2\left(1-\frac\mu2\right)$$
with $\mu=\pm\mu_3$, $\mu_3=e^{2\pi i/3}$, and where the main cardioid are the points for $|\mu| \leqslant 1.$  Hence you can use the family of parameters $c(\lambda\cdot\mu_3)$ with $\lambda\in\mathbb R$ where the transitions occurs at $\lambda=\pm 1$.

We can also give explicit values where "$n$-furcation" 1→$n$ is happening, namely at $c(e^{2\pi i/n})$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2D images of multifurcations :

[image: trifurcation]

[image: 4-furcation]

[image: 5-furcation]

These are images of the limit cycles for c along [escape routes](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/0025570X.2002.11953112?journalCode=umma20) : 1/3, 1/4 i 2/5 so we have : 
trifurcation, 4-furcation  and 5-furcations.

More description by [Claude](https://mathr.co.uk/blog/) ( [author of the code](https://fractalforums.org/fractal-mathematics-and-new-theories/28/tri-furcation-and-more/1247/msg6431#msg6431) ):

> For non-real C you can plot all the limit-cycle Z on one image, chances of overlap are small.